# Bumblebee optirun appears to depend on Intel

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I have a Lenovo T420 with Intel and Nvidia graphics. On upgrade to Ubuntu Saucy, I had to purge and reinstall bumblebee-nvidia to get beyond optirun failing to find a GPU driver. Now, "optirun glxgears" and "optirun sol" succeed, but optirun fails on 2 Virtual Life viewers that it supported in the past, Cool VL (CoolVLViewer-1.26.8.34-Linux-x86) and Imprudence (Imprudence 1.4.0 beta2). In both cases, the error output is huge, but it starts with

> libGL error: failed to load driver: i965

and

> libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast

From the little I can discover, i965 is an Intel graphics driver, which should not be invoked at all. I haven't found any information about swrast. I suspect that some of the X configuration associated with Bumblebee has some Intel dependence that is invoked on certain library calls, but not others. I haven't discovered any definite information on this line.

The Cool VL Viewer runs *without* optirun, but complains about the insufficiency of the Intel graphics.

Answer (score 2):

I worked around the problem, without understanding the root of it, by entering two symbolic links:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri /usr/lib64/dri
```

creates

```
/usr/lib64/dri -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri
```

and

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri /usr/lib32/dri
```

creates

```
/usr/lib32/dri -> /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri
```

So now the libraries are found correctly

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem and I got the swrast error to go away after running:

```
apt-get install libgl1-mesa-swx11
```

Now  `optirun glxinfo` runs ok.